A strange confusion over a problem of continuity in Multivariate Calculus.
For $\beta\in\Bbb R,$  define $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}\cfrac{x^2|x|^{\beta}y}{x^4+y^2},&x\neq 0 \\ 0, &x=0 \end{cases}$$
Prove that at $(0,0)$ the function is discontinuous if $\beta=0.$
My solution goes like this:
We can prove that $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$ if, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)\neq f(0,0).$
We try to show that in this case, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist.
A general strategy to show this, is to take two functions, say $y=\phi(x)$ and $y=\psi(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0}\phi(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\psi(x)=0$ and show that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,\phi(x))\neq \lim_{x\to 0} f(x,\psi(x))$ (, also we note that, as $x\to 0$ we have, $(x,y)=(x,\phi(x))\to(0,0)$ and $(x,y)=(x,\phi(x))\to (0,0)$).
We let $y=\phi(x)=x$ and $y=\psi(x)=x^2.$ We have, $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \cfrac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}, & x\neq 0 \\ 0,&x=0 \end{cases}$$ and so, if $L=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ exists then, $L=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,\phi(x))=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3}{x^4+x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x^2+1}=0$.
Again, $L=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,\psi(x))=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^4}{x^4+x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{2}=\frac 12.$
This is what we've wanted to show and $L=\frac 12$ gives us a contradiction as $\frac 12\neq 0.$
So, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist. This proves that at $(0,0)$ the function is discontinuous if $\beta=0.$

On second thought, I tried to prove the same thing using the "approach of polar  coordinates' as follows:
Just like the previous approach, we try to show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist but this time using polar coordinates.
We have,
$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\cfrac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}=\lim_{r\to 0} \cfrac {r^3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{r^4\cos^4\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta}=\lim_{r\to 0} \cfrac {r\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{r^2\cos^4\theta+\sin^2\theta}=0.$
So, surprisingly we end up seeing that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=f(0,0)$ due to which we may conclude that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0).$

Both approaches should have given me the same conclusion, but this is not happening in my case. However, I don't understand where did I go wrong in this second approach of mine? Is my first approach, correct? Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

The second approach does not prove that $f$ is continuous (or not continuous) at $(0, 0)$ - it's inconclusive. The first approach proves that $f$ is not continuous at $(0, 0)$.

@K. Jiang How do you say that the second approach is inconclusive?

Why specify $\beta$ if it plays no part in the problem???

@copper.hat Good point. But it doesn't matter anyways.

For the "polar test" to be conclusive in showing that $\lim_{(x, y) \to O} f (x, y) = L$, two conditions together are necessary (and sufficient):
(1) For each $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$, the limit $\lim_{r \to 0} f (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$ must exist and equal $L$.
(2) The limit in (1) is uniform in $\theta$. That is, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there must exist some $\delta$ such that $|f (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) - L| < \varepsilon$ for $r < \delta$ and all $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$.
This fact is proven nicely here.
In your case, (1) is certainly satisfied, since for $\theta \ne 0$,
$$\lim_{r \to 0} f (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r \cos^2 \theta \sin \theta}{r^2 \cos^4 \theta + \sin^2 \theta} = 0$$
and for $\theta = 0$, the limit becomes $\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{0}{r^2} = 0$.
This is all you checked, so with just (1), the continuity of $f$ at $O$ is indeed inconclusive, as I mentioned.
Your situation fails to satisfy (2): the limit is not uniform in $\theta$. This you have effectively already shown. For any fixed $r > 0$, the value of $f (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$ can always be made to be $\frac{1}{2}$ when $\cos \theta \cot \theta = \frac{1}{r}$. So, no $\delta$ exists for $\varepsilon < \frac{1}{2}$, showing that the limit $\lim_{(x, y) \to O} f (x, y)$ is not $0$.

Thanks your explanation seems to be the most rigorous ones I have seen so far. Though, I haven't learnt multivariate analysis, but having studied real analysis, this somewhat makes some real sense to me.

Glad to help. You can think of this as a generalization of the ideas from real analysis. In an arbitrary metric space $X$, a function $f: X \to Y$ has limit $L$ at $x_0 \in X$ if, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < d (x, x_0) < \delta \implies d (f (x), L) < \varepsilon$. If $X, Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ then we can simply take $d (x, x') = |x' - x|$. For your problem, $X, Y = \mathbb{R}^2$, where we take $d (x, x') = ||x' - x||$. The two conditions listed in my answer enforce the general definition of the limit for this case.

From the purely logical standpoint:

The equality
\begin{equation} \tag{$1$} \lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} g(x, y) = \ell \end{equation}
holds if and only if the equality
\begin{equation} \tag{$2$} \lim_{t \to 0} g(\varphi(t), \psi(t)) = \ell \end{equation}
holds for every continuous curve $(x, y) = (\varphi(t), \psi(t))$ with $(\varphi(0), \psi(0)) = (0, 0)$.


In your first approach you found two curves that gave different values of the limit ($2$). This correctly proves that the limit ($1$) does not exist.

In your second approach you essentially proved that when the curve $(\varphi(t), \psi(t))$ is any straight line, the value of the limit ($2$) equals $0$. This does not prove that the limit ($1$) equals $0$, because you haven't considered every possible curve.


The reason why your approach with polar coordinates is equivalent to computing the limit over a straight line (rather than an arbitrary curve) is as follows: the limit
$$\lim_{r \to 0} g(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$$
is a special case of the limit ($2$), where $\varphi(r) = r \cos \theta$ and $\psi(r) = r \sin \theta$. The curve that it gives, i.e. $\{ (\varphi(r), \psi(r)) : r \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is a straight line going in the direction of $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$.

I am confused. I can say that I have seen tons of examples that substitues $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$  and evaluates the limit. I think a possible explanation is: when asked to check the existence of a limit or to determine whether a function is continuous at $(0,0)$, we may use the polar coordinate approach if we find that $\lim_{r\to 0}f(rcos\theta,r\sin\theta)=0$ no matter what the value of $\theta$ is, i.e for every choice of $\theta$ the function $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ must be defined. Is my inference written in italics correct?

@ThomasFinley No, this is precisely the mistake. You can prove that a limit doesn't exist by using polar coordinates and getting two different values for two different $\theta$s. But you can not prove that a limit exists with polar coordinates, unless you do it very carefully, namely - by allowing $\theta$ to depend on $r$. If you treat $\theta$ as an arbitrary constant under the limit as $r \to 0$, you are inevitably only checking straight lines rather than arbitrary curves, which is not sufficient to prove that the limit exists.

This is a very common misconception, so it is not out of question that the "ton of examples" you saw were straight up wrong. If they were somehow right, they must have been way more elaborate than your description seems to indicate. For a rough estimate, if the solutions had $\theta$ rather than $\theta(r)$, and the word "uniformly" was never used, and the conclusion was that the limit exists - they were almost certainly wrong.

Converting to polar coordinates does not alter the fact that, along the curve $y=x^2$, the fraction has constant value equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.
If you liked you could substitute polar coordinates to convert the equation of the curve $y=x^2$ to $r \sin \theta = r^2 \cos^2 \theta$; when you cancel the $r$ that becomes $\sin\theta =r \cos^2 \theta$. Substituting this into the polar coordinate fraction, the numerator becomes $r^2 \cos^4 \theta$ and the denominator becomes $2r^2 \cos^4 \theta$ and so the whole thing simplifies to a constant value of $\frac{1}{2}$ along that curve, just as it did in Cartesian coordinates.
So the lesson remains the same: just because you are letting $r \to 0$ you are not free to "hold $\theta$ fixed". You have to consider the limit along all possible ways to let $r$ approach zero, even along curves like $\sin\theta = r \cos^2\theta.$

I am not holding $\theta$ fixed. I allowed $\theta$ to be anything. Even if, $\sin \theta=0$ then also, the limit is $0.$ Somehow, I remain in confusion. For example see here

Let me put this another way. You are not allowing the ordered pair $(r,\theta)$ to be anything. Instead, you are first fixing $\theta$, and only after having fixed $\theta$ are you letting $r$ approach $0$... and this is not how the limit is defined. You must instead consider all ways that the ordered pair $(r,\theta)$ can vary as $r$ appoaches zero. So, for instance, you should take into account how how the ordered pair $(r,\theta)$ varies along the curve $\sin(\theta)=r \cos^2(\theta)$.

Try it out numerically. Let $\theta = .1$ and $r = \frac{\sin(.1)}{\cos^2(.1)}= 0.100838444$, and compute the value of your fractional function of $r$ and $\theta$. Then do the same with $\theta=.01$, and with $\theta=.001$, and so on. That should convince you: you'll see that $r$ is approaching zero, but your fractional function is staying constant at $\frac{1}{2}$ (to the accuracy of your calculational tools, that is).

To put it another way, if you aren't holding $\theta$ fixed, then how are you finding that $\lim_{r\to 0}...=0$?
